# ASP.NET MVC - Lock and Unlock User in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As a low level developer, I am working on a project on User Management using ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET mvc.

Please how do I do the following:

1. Automatically lock the user after 5 failed login attempt.
2. Manually unlock the user by the Admin after a request.
3. Send e-mail to selected users based on role or even all users

How do I use the ASP.NET Identity in MVC to write the code for the user interface.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to do more research on this. SO it here to help with specific coding problems you have encountered. All this information is available online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can set `MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout=5` as in below. you can find this at

> IdentityConfig.cs

```
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

And you can set shouldLockout equal to true in login then it makes lockout in 5 times.

```
 await `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);`
```

2. you can see below code in

> Identityconfig.cs

```
 manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

According to the minutes, you set, will generate timestamp on AspNetUsers table  LockoutEndDateUtc column.According to setup time, you can edit the time backward 5 minutes as in this scenario.You can do this using an interface for the particular requester querying by userid and modify LockoutEndDateUtc respectively.

3.Your roles are store in AspNetRoles table and users map their roles with AspnetUserRoles table. You can query particular roles and retrieve users mail address. Set up the mail server for sending emails.

here is code for setup Gmail

var SenderEmail = new MailAddress("sendermail", "");
        var ReciverEmail = new MailAddress("Destinationmail", "");

```
    var Password = "";
    var subject = "";
    var body = message.Body;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SenderEmail.Address, Password)

    };
    using (var mess = new MailMessage(SenderEmail, ReciverEmail)
    {
        Subject = "",
        Body = ""
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(mess);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate. But how do I manually (from an interface) unlock a locked user. Also, how, how do I send e-mail to selected users

Comment: @olugbenga for the third question you can have the email address from hep of above tables and can set up your own mail server as you wish.

Comment: I really appreciate. Please can you give me a sample of how I can query the Users based on Role