# How to configure login attempts and also unlock by administrator manually in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203994/asp-net-mvc-lock-and-unlock-user-in-asp-net-identity) but there are many things are missing in ASP.NET Core 2.0.

I made shouldLockout: true

```
await `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);`
```

Now user Locked out after five failed attempts and also automatically unlock after sometime(approx. 5 mins).

Where can I change the number of attempts like in old ASP.NET versions

```
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
```

and also how administrator can able to unlock manually within that period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the number of attempts, set it in the identity options:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    // Lockout settings
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5; 
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

To unlock the user, reset the lockout end date. Something like: `await _userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, null);` where `user` is the user to unlock.